# VBA @ Access on replacing values on a huge list

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a question (that's why I'm here actually :P ) about VBA @ MS Access.

So, I have a huge database (well, for me it is huge, about 23K+ ID) on shoes. It has 5 columns: ID, Article number, size (mm),pairs (avaliable on stock) and EAC13 codes. It is updated daily. Everyday I get the update on it, on CSV (all those ID all over again) and create new tables, although I just need to update stock availability. However there is one column that I have to change in order to get reports: Sizes. I have to get 2 reports, one where I get the size of the shoe in mm and the other where the size is on European measure. For example: 245 mm is equal to a 35. Simple as that. I have a VBA that I thought it could help me to replace all those values (yes, all the 23k on the "size" column), that goes like this

```
Public Sub Substitui()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM BS_2704"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
For Each fld In rst.Fields
If fld.Value = "150" Then
rst.Edit
fld.Value = "24"
rst.Update
End If

If fld.Value = "160" Then
rst.Edit
fld.Value = "25"
rst.Update
End If

(...)

If fld.Value = "325" Then
rst.Edit
fld.Value = "50"
rst.Update
End If


Next fld
rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Anyway...this only changes 150 entries (more or less). The million dollar question is, is there any kind of line that I am missing here in order to get this VBA to change ALL the 23k entries?

I am a n00b on this fields, so I would appreciate some n00b therms for a start. Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can guess why your VBA is only changing around 150 records instead of all of them, but more importantly, you need to know that the specific method you're using--changing *all* the fields using VBA--can lead to incorrect data in your table. And, you can accomplish what you want *much* more easily with a SQL query ... even one made using the query designer. But for now I'll stick with plain SQL. There are three possibilities and corresponding approaches:

`1` You just have to change a limited number of different sizes from mm to European. In that case use the `switch` function, e.g.:

```
update BS_2704
set Sizes = switch(
  Sizes = 150, 24
, Sizes = 160, 25
, ...
, Sizes = 325, 50
, true, Sizes
)
```

`2` You can use a mathematical formula to convert from your mm size to your European measure, e.g. like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_size#Europe:

```
update BS_2704
set Sizes = Sizes * 3 / 20
```

`3` You can't use a mathematical formula, *and* you have such a large number of conversion mappings that putting them all in a single `switch` function is unwieldy: in this case you create a new table, e.g. named `tblSizeMappings`, with the mm sizes and the corresponding European sizes:

```
SizeMM SizeEuropean
   150           24
   160           25
   325           50
```

Then, do an update query like above but using the `tblSizeMappings` table to get the European sizes:

```
update BS_2704
inner join tblSizeMappings
on BS_2704.Sizes = tblSizeMappings.SizeMM
set BS_2704.Sizes = tblSizeMappings.SizeEuropean
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. Although I didn't have a clue were could I place such lines, I figured it out after long minutes trying to figure it out. Thumbs up on this one!